# SpringBoot Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'beanNamePlaceholderRegistryPostProcessor'

Tags: spring-boot

I recently started getting this warning on start up of my Spring Boot application:

> o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Cannot enhance
>   @Configuration bean definition
>   'beanNamePlaceholderRegistryPostProcessor' since its singleton
>   instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static
>   @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type:
>   Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.

I cannot figure out where it is coming from. I have no such classes ('beanNamePlaceholderRegistryPostProcessor', 'BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor') in my app that I can find so not sure how to prevent this from happening.

Anyone have any ideas?

This question is slightly different to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614313/warn-about-non-static-configurationclasspostprocessor-declarations-on-configura) as that one seems to be with a class that the user has created.

Answer (score 5):

I finally discovered that **beanNamePlaceholderRegistryPostProcessor** is part of the Jasypt Spring Boot starter package.

I raised a ticket about it and the author replied immediately, indicating that it is nothing to worry about.

https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/issues/45

You can ignore the warning if you want by adding the following to Logback (if you use that):

```
<logger name="org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor" level="ERROR"/>
```

Comment: some warnings are important. it will be much interesting to search for a fixing solution